# Compare List of Integers and add/remove the rows in database using the difference in result LinqtoSQL

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-sql

Currently I'm working on a project using LinqtoSql and I would like to get an simpler solution for my current problem.

Example:
 Lets say I got a table named `Example` with three rows (with values 1,2,4)
 Now in code(c#) I got these values as a list of Integer(lets name it `lstExisting`)
Now in my method I got another List  of Integer ( say `lstCurrent`) with Integers values (1,2,3)
Now I want to compare the  both the list and find the difference of integers and update the database, so according to my example a new row with value 3 should be added and the existing row with value 4 should be deleted. 
PS:(the integer values will be always unique and will be 1,2,3,4)
Linq solutions will be preferable but I don't mind other easier solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find new items and to be deleted items using `Except` like:

```
var newItems = lstCurrent.Except(lstExisting).ToList();
var toBeDeletedItems = lstExisting.Except(lstCurrent).ToList();
```

Later you can iterate each list and Add/Delete accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Contains()`. With having two lists, you can write something like this. What this does is it iterates over each item in your methods list and checks the original to see if its there.

```
var lstExisting = getExistingList();
var lstCurrent = getCurrentList();

foreach(var currentInt in lstCurrent)
{
    if(!lstExisting.Contains(currentInt))
    {
        //insert currentInt
    }
```